# NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification infinite loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data

See this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:retriever.managedObjectContext
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
{
    NSLog(@"lalala");
    NSLog(@"Note : %@",note);
}];
```

During object's change on the same thread and context as the observed one, I get an infinite loop of blocks' invocation if the second NSLog is uncommented, otherwise everything works fine. What's going on here?

Comment: You always have to do stuff on the context and thread the object has been created, as with NSConfinementConcurrencyType.

Comment: Make sure that your `retriever.managedObjectContext` is not nil, if it's nil you will receive notifications from all the frameworks that use Core Data.

Comment: It is certainly not nil.

Comment: It's actually a loop, in the sense that the block calls pile up on the stack recursively? Or is it a lot of independent non-looped calls? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in this block? Looking over the call stack is likely to help.

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes, actually it is all being sent by core data internals - they come up as an assembly. Tried breakpoints, but can't fight ldr/b combo... So, it is not a strict loop, it's just that calling description on one of CD objects that triggers looped updates. Still do not know why, though...